# Using markers and polylines with google maps api

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I have a map and it has both markers and polylines.

Now I need to seperate these polylines and the markers on different layers I.E

When i want to remove the polylines i just execute the method with layer name that removes the polyline's layer

can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by layers, but check the docs.

[Google Maps API Docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html)  Sepcifically, look at GPolyline.hide();